# Custom method for field

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I used cookiecutter django to create a project and django builder for my first app to get up and running quickly. I'm using crispy forms and I want to replace the default checkbox with an image.

I have a model with only boolean fields - I want to display images depending on the field is set true or false in the form.

I got a function which maps the column name to a image path which I can use in the template but I have no idea how to do it without adding a function call to the template

Ideally I would have a `field.image` method which I can insert in the src element, my function call looks like this

```
image_src = image_path(field.label)
```

And as I see the best access to the field.label is in this template.

Thats my custom template I want to use

```
{% load crispy_forms_field %}

<li>
  {% crispy_field field 'class' 'custom-control-input' %}
  <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}"><img src="{{ field.image }}" alt="{{ field.label }}"/></label>
</li>
```

This is my forms.py

```
    class ProtectiveEquipmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = ProtectiveEquipment

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.helper = FormHelper()

            self.helper.layout = Layout(
                Fieldset(
                'first arg is the legend of the fieldset',
                Field('head_protection', 'eye_protection',
                       'template="graphical_checkbox.html"),
                template="graphical_checkbox_list.html"
                ),
                ButtonHolder(
                    Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='button white')
                )
            )
            super(ProtectiveEquipmentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

got if working with custom filter

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

from .utils import name_to_image_path

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
@stringfilter
def image_uri(value):
    return name_to_image_path(value)
```

and then in the template `{{ form.label | name_to_image_path }}`
more info here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/